# Intellij application.yml throwing ScannerException reading tags from pom file but not in build

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to reference the starter parent in `info:app:parent` and used `info:app:parent: @project.parent.version@`. This wasn't an issues when I used it for `info:app:version: @java.version@` but it throws the following exception when I do so:

```
11:28:01.627 [restartedMain] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication -- Application run failed
org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: while scanning for the next token
found character '@' that cannot start any token. (Do not use @ for indentation)
 in 'reader', line 17, column 13:
        parent: @project.parent.version@
                ^
```

Additionally, it is not an issue when I use `info:app:parent: @parent@` but is when I use `info:app:parent: @parent.version@`.

I didn't understand so I built the app with mvn using `mvn package -DskipTests` and ran it with the following args `mvn spring-boot:run -D"spring-boot.run.profiles"=prod -D"spring-boot.run.arguments"="<args>"` and when I hit the actuator endpoint for info I got the parent version. I reloaded pom.xml, ran `mvn clean`, invalidated caches and restarted intellij, and none of these worked. I am running java 21 with spring boot parent 3.1.4. Downgrading to java 17 and spring boot parent 3.1.3 did not solve this. My project structure is fine, and the run configuration is aligned with my specified java version in the pom file. This is an issue with intellij and was wondering if anyone has ever had this happen to them. Enclosing with single quotes just gives me the placeholder and using `^` instead of `@` is the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: Add new element `<app.version>${parent.version}</app.version>` to the properties element and reference that. Maven will inject whatever value the parent version is so you won't have to maintain this tag.

I have confirmed it is an issue with the IDE, as this doesn't occur when I build the application with maven. I upgraded to 2023.2.2 and the issue persisted. Upgrading the snakeyaml version doesn't resolve the problem. The only solution is to create a new tag in properties and reference that.`@parent.artifactId@` and `@parent.groupId@` work just fine. Adding a single quote throws an exception (except with properties file), but oddly doesn't affect injecting the maven property which allowed me to confirmed that the `@parent.version@` is the only maven property that doesn't get injected.

Additionally, using a properties file instead of a yml file doesn't make a difference: this specific tag does not get injected.